# A method to solve a system of nonlinear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is the system of ODE

$$x'(t)=y$$
$$y'(t)=\frac{x^2}{2}$$

solvable through analytic means? I might be missing something, since by the chain rule the second equation gives the second order ODE $y''=xy$, which doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Solve instead $x''=\frac{x^2}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint.

Multiplying side to side

$$
\cases{
x' = y\\
\frac{x^2}{2} = y'
}\ \ \ \Rightarrow \frac 12\left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)' = \frac 12\left(y^2\right)'
$$

then we obtain one movement constant

$$
\frac{x^3}{3} = y^2 + C_1
$$